# How to create a trigger in Oracle with this requirements

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have created 3 tables:

- `student` table with columns `sid`, `sname` and `dept`
- `mca` table with columns `sid` and `sname`
- `mba` table with columns `sid` and `sname`

Now I want to create a trigger so that when the value in `dept` is `mca` then `sid` and `sname` also go into the `mca` table, and if it is `mba` then they go into the `mba` table.

This is what I have tried, [based on a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20677433):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MY_TRIGG
AFTER INSERT ON STUDENTS
BEGIN
IF STUDENTS.DPTID=101 THEN
INSERT INTO MCA VALUES(:NEW.SID,:NEW.SNAME);
ELSIF STUDENTS.DPTID=102 THEN
INSERT INTO MCA VALUES(:NEW.SID,:NEW.SNAME);
ELSE
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NO DEPARTMENT IS FOUND');
END;
```

This shows an error: NEW OR OLD REFERENCES NOT ALLOWED IN TABLE LEVEL TRIGGERS

Answer (score 0):

You have a statement-level trigger, but you seem to want a row-level trigger, so you need the [`for each row` clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/create_trigger.htm#sthref1380). Your `DPTID` references should also be against the current row, from `:NEW` rather than `STUDENTS`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MY_TRIGG
AFTER INSERT ON STUDENTS
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :NEW.DPTID=101 THEN
    INSERT INTO MCA (SID, SNAME) VALUES (:NEW.SID,:NEW.SNAME);
  ELSIF :NEW.DPTID=102 THEN
    INSERT INTO MBA (SID, SNAME) VALUES (:NEW.SID,:NEW.SNAME);
  ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NO DEPARTMENT IS FOUND');
  END IF;
END;
```

I added a missing `END IF` too. You might want to consider a `CASE` statement rather then `IF/ELSIF/ELSE`. And you should really explicitly list the column names as part of your `INSERT` statements.

Having a `DBMS_OUTPUT` call in a trigger isn't very useful, as you can't assume whoever is doing the insert will see it. It's more common to throw an exception if some criteria isn't met, and that would prevent the insert on the master table as well.